# How to read first row data as start time , end of the day last row as end time and continue to next day import from csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas

Here I have time series with date from csv file. So in time column first time I want to read it as start time and it will continue with one hour delta time till to end of the day time. Then again it will continue to next day first time as a start time. This is a continue process. Can you help me to solve this problem?
 Here is subset of my data set,

[image]

I wrote one code just display date and I don't know how to proceed my code?

```
data = pd.read_csv('data9.csv')
data['Date']=pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format="%m/%d/%Y")
print(data['Date'])
data['Time']= data['Time'].str.split(':').apply(lambda x: int(x[0]) * 60 + int(x[1]))
print(data['Time'])
```

Then I want to give time duration one hour first time to next time to predict value with time.

```
def make_dates(start_date, number_of_days, start_time, end_time, interval):
if isinstance(start_date, datetime.datetime):
    start_date = start_date.date()
start_date = datetime.datetime.combine(start_date, start_time)
cur_date = start_date
num_days_passed = 0
step = datetime.timedelta(seconds=interval*60)

while True:
    new_date = cur_date + step
    if new_date.time() > end_time:
        num_days_passed += 1
        if num_days_passed > number_of_days:
            break
        new_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=num_days_passed)
    ret_date, cur_date = cur_date, new_date
    yield ret_date

Time = make_dates(datetime.datetime.now(), 3, datetime.time(hour=6), datetime.time(hour=23), 60, None)
```

Output should have to come like this:-

```
2018-09-01 06:00', '2018-09-01 07:00', '2018-09-01 08:00', '2018-09-01 09:00', '2018-09-01 10:00', '2018-09-01 11:00', '2018-09-01 12:00', '2018-09-01 13:00'..
```

So here date is should have to includ csv file date time start should have to time column first time on that day and end time also and this is continues to next day.

Comment: "So here date is should have to includ csv file date time start should have to time column first time on that day and end time also and this is continues to next day." It's not clear to me what you're asking. Any chance you could show us what output you're expecting?

Comment: @marco_gorelli Actually I have a dataset with time series . Here I want continue the time with  one hour duration satrting from time import from csv file  till to end of the day end time . Then I want to continue it to next day with time (include in csv file time with next day) as start time end of the day it will end  and will continue to next day .  Here I upload how I my output looks like. Can you suggest me best options to solve this process?